# Two date columns in source to decide the latest updated record in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement as below:
I have a source table like

```
id | name | address | updt_date_1 | updt_date_2
1  | abc  | xyz     | 2000-01-01  | 1999-01-01
1  | abc  | pqr     | 2001-01-01  | 1999-01-01
2  | lmn  | ghi     | 1999-01-01  | 1999-01-01
2  | lmn  | stu     | 2000-01-01  | 2008-01-01
```

I would want to get in target as:

```
1 | abc | pqr 
2 | lmn | stu
```

i.e. I would want the record with the latest update date in either of the two date columns -updt_date_1 or updt_date_2

Please suggest how can this be implemented in informatica PC

Answer (score 1):

This requirement can be achieved in a effective way by using just 3 transformations (SourceQualifier, Expression and Filter). Please see the steps below

1) Use the following SQL override in the Source Qualifier transformation to reduce the two last_updated_date fields into one

```
SELECT
    id
    ,name
    ,address
    ,CASE WHEN updt_date_1 > updt_date_2 THEN updt_date_1 ELSE updt_date_2 AS updt_date 
FROM souce_table 
ORDER BY id, updt_date DESC
```

Now the first row for each id will be the required record.

2)  Use an expression transformation to flag the first row of each id. Use the following ports in the same order in the expression transformation (prefix o_ means output port, v_ means variable port and i_ means input port)

```
PORT               EXPRESSION
v_FIRST_ROW_FLAG - IIF(v_PREV_ID==i_id,'N','Y')
v_PREV_ID        - i_id
o_FIRST_ROW_FLAG - v_FIRST_ROW_FLAG
```

3) Next add a filter transformation to filter records which does not satisfy the  following condition

```
IIF(o_FIRST_ROW_FLAG==Y,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Connect this filter transformation to the target definition. This will give you the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we have to determine maximum update date1 and update date2. Then we have to choose which one is maximum between them.

1. Usea souce qualifier and then sort the data based on id, name.
2. Add an aggregtor after. pull id, name, updt_date_1, updt_date_2 columns. Create two o/p columns - max_upd_dt1, max_upd_dt2 and calculate MAX(updt_date_1), MAX(updt_date_2) respectively . set group by id, name.
3. Use a joiner to join sorter output and aggregator output based on id,name. so now you have two extra columns- max_upd_dt1 and max_upd_dt2.
4. Use an expression transformation after joiner. Pull all columns in. Create two output port and set logic like below -
   out_upd_dt1 = iif( max_upd_dt1 > max_upd_dt2, max_upd_dt1, updt_date_1 )
   out_upd_dt2 = iif( max_upd_dt1 < max_upd_dt2, max_upd_dt2, updt_date_2 )
5. Use another source qualifier(sort by id,name)and join it with above expression tx. Join based on -
   id=id, name=name, out_upd_dt1=updt_date_1, out_upd_dt2= updt_date_2
6. Pick up id, name, address

HTH

Koushik